# Is there a formula for $f(n)=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{\sin^{2}(\frac{\pi }{k})}$

Tags: trigonometry, summation

I wonder is there formula for this function.

$$f(n)=\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{\sin^{2}(\frac{\pi }{k})}$$

Comment: For large $k$, $\sin\frac\pi k\approx\frac\pi k$, so $f(n)-f(n-1)\approx \frac{n^2}{\pi^2}$ for large $n$, which make $f(n)\sim \frac1{3\pi^2}n^3$

Comment: Is there a reason to think that this has a closed form? Where did it come from?